# MALLOC_TRACE for Windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, memory-leaks, mtrace

In our company we have an inhouse framework similar to the [mtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace) (MALLOC_TRACE) functionality in glibc for detecting memory leaks. This framework is written to run on Windows, but it doesn't work very well in GNU/Linux.

So, do anybody know of a portable equivalent to mtrace (MALLOC_TRACE), that can run on Windows, GNU/Linux and hopefully even MacOSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried dmalloc?

http://dmalloc.com/

perhaps I think on linux valgrind is much better

Comment: dmalloc is certainly an alternative. It would be interesting to hear peoples experiences running it under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A few month ago, I developed the base for a portable C library, allowing some kind of OOP.

Memory is managed with reference counting, and the project includes a memory debugger, that keep track of all allocations, providing extended debug informations when necessary.

It's published under the BOOST license, so you're free to use it.

https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/

Current revision is actually in a non-workable state, but you may check older ones, to see how it's done.

A working version is available in the tags ([1.2.2-0](https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/zipball/1.2.2-0)). This one builds fine on OSX, Windows and Linux.

Memory stuff is located mainly in the `source/core` directory:

- [XSMemory.c](https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/blob/master/source/core/XSMemory.c)
- [XSMemoryDebug.c](https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/blob/master/source/core/XSMemoryDebug.c)
- [__XSMemory.c](https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/blob/master/source/core/__XSMemory.c)
- [__XSMemoryDebug.c](https://github.com/macmade/XSFoundation/blob/master/source/core/__XSMemoryDebug.c)

Here's the kind of output for a SegmentationFault, for instance:

[image]

You can then get backtrace informations, display allocations, etc.